# Zend Framework 2 - Some Begginner Questions

Tags: zend-framework2

this is my first question,

I'm a ZF2 Beginner and I have some questions related with the tutorial I'm following ("Zend Franework 2 by Example").

I follow the instructions but when I'm going to test the result, links missmatch and do not link to their correctly route. My explanation.

I've created a new one Users module following the skeletonModule structure for ZF2. The module.config.php code is

```
    <?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Users\Controller\Index' => 
            'Users\Controller\IndexController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'users' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    // Change this to something specific to your module
                    'route'    => '/users',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Users\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    // This route is a sane default when developing a module;
                    // as you solidify the routes for your module, however,
                    // you may want to remove it and replace it with more
                    // specific routes.
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'users' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

My next step was create 3 .phtml pages called "index.phtml", "login.phtml" and "new-user.phtml". Index is the main page (obviously) and is linked to the other two.

Index code is:

```
<h1>Bienvenido al modulo de usuarios</h1>
<a href="../users/index/login">Login</a> || 
<a href="../users/index/register">Registro</a>
```

Login code is:

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<p>Esta página contendrá el formulario de inicio de sesión (Login).</p>
<a href="../">Volver a inicio.</a>
```

New-user code is:

```
<h2>Registro de nuevo usuario</h2>
<p>Esta página contendrá el formulario de registro para un nuevo usuario.</p>
<a href="../">Volver a inicio.</a>
```

Here is my doubt. In the tutorial the href links are different than mine. For index.phtml tutorial code is `<a href="/users/index/login">Login</a> || <a href="/users/index/register">Registro</a>` NOT `<a href="../users/index/login">Login</a> || 
    <a href="../users/index/register">Registro</a>`

If I change my href links like tutorial mentions it doesn't work and redirect to an error page cause ZF2 do not locate the other phtml files. If I put the links with "../" my project works OK.

I cannot post any picture but if you want and can help me, I send the project structure pic to your email. Thanks 4 all!

Comment: Is ZF2 running in a sub-folder?

Comment: ZF2 is running under http://localhost/ZF2_TUTORIAL1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never faced that issue, 
anyway, is that project running on localhost? Which url are you visiting to see your homepage?

I also suggest you to use the [url view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html) to render your urls

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('users/default', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'login')); ?>">Login</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm working on localhost domain, so I'm testing the app under http://localhost/ZF2_TUTORIAL1/public/users/. The main Users index.php is under this directory.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot give you my THANKS!! With url viewer helper works perfectly!